# Как получить тип из экземпляра Type?

Tags: c#, ооп, типы-данных

Есть две функции.

```
public void Add(Type type)
{
   var stream = GetStream<T>();//передать вместо T тип переданный в переменную type (MyClass)
}

private IObjectStream<T> GetStream<T>() 
{
   return default(T);
}
```

Вызов метода

```
Add(typeof(MyClass));
```

Как мне передать в универсальный метод GetStream тип который был передан в переменную type?

Comment: почему не `public void Add<T>()` ? И вызов потом `Add<MyClass>()`

Comment: Или же вопрос должен быть "как мне вызвать generic-метод обладая объектом Type?"

Comment: public void Add<T>() тоже подойдет, просто хотел сделать по другому.